# What's the unit of fine-structure constant?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

What's the unit of [fine-structure constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant)? I mean in SI units.

Comment: It has no units. It's a number, like 2 or pi.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is easily found in numerous references as well as at the linked wiki.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's off-topic. I think a brief explanation of how it's dimensionless in both SI and cgs even though its algebraic expression looks quite different in each case could be useful, as this is a common source of confusion. Whether this would be redundant is another question.